# reinterpret_cast / static_cast / C cast operator

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

I need to transfer the following message from one process to anther over the network.

```
typedef struct {
    int msgType;
    int msgLen;
} msgHeader;

typedef struct 
{
    payload data;
} payload;
```

Sender:

```
sender(msgHeader *mh,payload *msg){
    void *sendBuf;
    void *p;
    sendBuf = (void *) malloc(sizeof(msgHeader)+sizeof(payload));
    p=sendBuf;
    memcpy(p,mh,sizeof(msgHeader));
    p+=sizeof(msgHeader);
    memcpy(p,msg,sizeof(payload);

    send(sendBuf,totalsize);
}
```

Receiver:

```
receive (void *p)
{
    msgHeader *mh;
    payload *msg;

    mh = XXXXX(p);
    msg = XXXXX (p+1);
}
```

In the above snippet, in the receiver, should I user reinterpret_cast or static_cast or the normal C cast operator in line marked XXXXX ?
I think any of these should work in this case ??

Comment: Does this compile?Why are you using `malloc`? Why all the `void`

Comment: `p+1` is undefined behaviour when `p` is a `void` pointer.  GCC (`g++`) will add 1, but that is a non-standard extension.

Comment: In C++ you should have a pretty good reason for using C's malloc/free instead of new/delete.